# Samsung s4 app devopment using afiledialog - directory contents not shown

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to start some app development.  For something I want to work on I want to process a file.  So I will have a file stored on the phone and I will do something to it.  I incorporate the 'afiledialog' library into my code.  It opens the activity and shows directories but the contents of the directories are empty.  For instance, if I click on the SDCARD folder there is nothing in it, even though I know there is.  I am using the code below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileChooserActivity.class);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    FileChooserDialog dialog = new FileChooserDialog(this);
    dialog.loadFolder(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/");
    dialog.show();
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Is it just a Kitkat issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that u need to make a difference between the two ways to access the storage

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

This refers to whatever the device manufacturer considered to be "external storage". On some devices, this is removable media, like an SD card. On some devices, this is a portion of on-device flash. Here, "external storage" means "the stuff accessible via USB Mass Storage mode when mounted on a host machine", at least for Android 1.x and 2.x.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

This one returns the path to internal SD mount point like "/mnt/sdcard"